# Passing data between forms in different applications

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, .net, sql-server

I have a situation here, I want data passed from application developed with PHP and MySQL to my ASP.Net Application. There is this application developed in PHP with MySQL database which was developed by another developer. I have a application or rather I am developing an application in ASP.net and I dont have access source of this application or the database. I want some data from that PHP application to passed to my ASP.net application. What I can do Is colaborate or ask that  PHP developer to supply the data in the format I want (XML or Json or any other technology) but I dont think that is secured way to do so. So I want to ask here what is my option here. What should I ask the PHP developer so that I get data into my application using best and secured way.

If my question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Create API to share the needed data across the 2 system
Option 2: Create Link servers to query from mySQL to MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how collaboratively you both work, but it sounds like the other developer will provide the data if you have a solution.

So, ask her to create a mySQL user that has read-only access to the database, then you can query it directly.

Comment: this is not the correct approach for 2 applications to talk to each other.